# How do I un-favorite a question that has been migrated to another SE site?

Tags: support, bookmarks, migrated-questions

Almost a month ago, I favorited [this question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/69409/song-playing-in-lift-me-up-first-dance-scene) which was originally asked on Movies & TV SE. It was later migrated to [Music Fans SE](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/4891/song-playing-in-lift-me-up-first-dance-scene).

I favorited this question to check its status. Now, it's been migrated and I want to un-favorite it. But I can't do that because I favorited it on M&TV, not on Music Fans.

So, my question is, **how do I un-favorite questions that has been migrated**?

Here are the screenshots if it can help.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use "?noredirect=1" in the end of the link.

For example, use this for your case:

> "movies.stackexchange.com/questions/69409/song-playing-in-lift-me-up-first-dance-scene?noredirect=1"

And then just unfavorite it by clicking on star.

Comment: What does the `noredirect` do?

Comment: @Ooker stop migrated question link to redirecting on secondary site and open the closed version from primary site only

Answer (score 12):

I found another way to un-favorite a question.

The trick is to go to [favorite](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/27264/a-j?tab=favorites) tab (taking my profile as an example) and click on the star on the left side of the question that I want to un-favorite.

Comment: that is what you shown in the question itself right?

Comment: Well, I didn't know that feature till then.